# #Bootstrap 3.2.0 #modal-dialogs #jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

following is the code for which modal-dialog is not popping up.I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and jquery is also above 1.9.0.Help me out if i am missing something.And please let me know for any further information and Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="modal fade" id = "login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal">Login or Registeration </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="jumbotron" id="home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>The Design Store</h1>
    <p>fdgdhfjgkhloj;jlkhhjgfdshjkl
      sgdhfjgkhkjlrtyguuhjkoxcvbn
      dgfhmb,nm,asdfghjkl;';lklkjhjhgfddfghjhg'..</p>
      <p>wefrgdthyjgukiosdfghjkgh
        ssdfghjklertyuwertyuicvbnm,
        sdfghjklsdfghjkljjhgfdsdfghjkjhgddsadfg</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">My Account</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any references to bootstrap javascript in the code? You need to load the bootstrap javascript for Modal dialogs to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct as far as markup (link below to view). Make sure you are including the jquery.js script before the bootstrap.js script.

[Working demo of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/jessejjohnson/vnxbkq7j/)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal">Login or Registeration </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>The Design Store</h1>
        <p>fdgdhfjgkhloj;jlkhhjgfdshjkl sgdhfjgkhkjlrtyguuhjkoxcvbn dgfhmb,nm,asdfghjkl;';lklkjhjhgfddfghjhg'..
        </p>
        <p>wefrgdthyjgukiosdfghjkgh ssdfghjklertyuwertyuicvbnm, sdfghjklsdfghjkljjhgfdsdfghjkjhgddsadfg
        </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">My Account</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated demo link to make sure its publicly available.